# Android logcat infinite messages

Tags: android, error-handling, android-camera, surfaceview, logcat

When i try to execute my app i get infinite number of messages which don't include my package name. I can't understand what they mean and which is the problem. Some of the messages in the logcat are the following:

```
03-01 21:51:21.980: I/SecCameraCoreManager(1555): SecCameraCoreManager created: pid=1555, cameraId=0
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555): > android::SteExtIspCamera::SteExtIspCamera(int) 
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555): < android::SteExtIspCamera::SteExtIspCamera(int)  
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555): > OMX_ERRORTYPE android::SteExtIspCamera::init() 
03-01 21:51:21.980: I/SteExtIspCamera(1555): debug.libcamera.level = 255
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555): > OMX_ERRORTYPE   android::SteExtIspCamera::initPrimaryDefaultParameters() 
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    Default preview Witdh: 640 Height: 480 framerate 30
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    Default preview framerate: 30
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    Default picture Width: 2560 Height: 1920 quality; 100 
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555): > virtual android::status_t android::SteExtIspCamera::setParameters(const android::CameraParameters&) 
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    Preview Width: 640 Height: 480  Format : yuv420sp
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    Record Width: 640 Height: 480
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    VPB0 Width: 640 Height: 480
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    Picture Width: 2560 Height: 1920 Format : jpeg Quality: 100
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    Thumbnail Width: 320 Height: 240 Quality: 70
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    Rotation: (null) WhiteBalance: auto Effect: none Antibanding: 50hz
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555):    SceneMode: auto Flash: off Focus: auto
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555): < virtual android::status_t android::SteExtIspCamera::setParameters(const android::CameraParameters&) 
03-01 21:51:21.980: D/SteExtIspCamera(1555): < OMX_ERRORTYPE android::SteExtIspCamera::initPrimaryDefaultParameters() 
03-01 21:51:21.980: I/ENSLoader(1555): CreateComponent OMX.ST.ExtHSMCamera
03-01 21:51:21.990: D/dalvikvm(17529): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 22K, 45% free 3521K/6343K, external 0K/0K, paused 77ms
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555): =========== persist.debug.extcamera.level enabled with level 777 =======
03-01 21:51:22.000: D/OSI-Trace(1555): EXTCAMERA > Camera 
03-01 21:51:22.000: D/OSI-Trace(1555):   > setDefaultFormatInPortDefinition 
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   PortIndex = 0
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.xFramerate         = 10
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.nFrameWidth        = 320
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.nFrameHeight       = 240 
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.eCompressionFormat = 0
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.eColorFormat       = 27
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.nStride            = 320
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.nSliceHeight       = 1
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.nBufferSize                     = 153600
03-01 21:51:22.000: D/OSI-Trace(1555):   > setDefaultFormatInPortDefinition 
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   PortIndex = 2
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.xFramerate         = 10
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.nFrameWidth        = 320
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.nFrameHeight       = 240 
03-01 21:51:22.000: I/OSI-Trace(1555):   mParamPortDefinition.format.video.eCompressionFormat = 0
```

what is going wrong?
Edit: My only thought is that in my centerLayout which is a cameraPreview(SurfaceView)i have a lot of relative layouts that overlay the cameraPreview and maybe this calculates all the time the dimensions and distances for every layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one Logcat-Log for the whole device - every thread running on your device will place its log-Statements there. On the left hand side of the logcat-window (Eclipse DDMS perspective) you can define filters to filter the output to your application's statements.